# http_build_query error when use params

Tags: php

```
$post_data = array(
    'model' => 'player',
    'action' => 'buyItem',
    'params' => array('item_id'=>100, 'count'=>100)
);
$postData = http_build_query($post_data);
echo $postData;


$post_data = array(
    'model' => 'player',
    'action' => 'buyItem',
    'arams' => array('item_id'=>100, 'count'=>100)
);
$postData = http_build_query($post_data);
echo $postData;
```

the first output was model=player&action=buyItem¶ms%5Bitem_id%5D=100¶ms%5Bcount%5D=100.
but the second output was right.
so why can't I use params as the key?
thanks!

Comment: I just see that in the 2nd array its `arams`, not `params`. These arrays are similar, i cant reproduce your failure.

Answer (score 2):

I can reproduce this.

It seems `params` is being converted to `&params` which is being interpreted as `&para` (¶ - paragraph) + `ms`.

Your solution would be to call `params` something else or, do:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($postData);
```

**Update.**

Actually, this only seems to happen if you try and echo `$postData`, if you use it as part of a URL it shows up correctly.

If you do something like:

```
echo "<a href='www.mysite.com?" . $postData . "'>Link</a>";
```

you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @Rikesh - glad it's not just my server then. ;)

Comment: @PeteR - Yeah. Though the reason is much clear in your answer, but rather I'm thinking of the cause & the solution.

Comment: I wonder what server configuration differences cause this to happen? Note that this also happens with other HTML entities such as _nbsp_, which results in a space in the URL...

Comment: @Rikesh: the solution would be to call `params` something else!

Comment: @FDL: hey, whatever works - I like easy... `htmlspecialchars` cures it too.

Comment: Many thanks! But I still don't know why params is being converted to &params. Does

Comment: @Michael: See update, the problem only seems to occur if you try to echo it, using it as part of a URL works fine.